# Property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'Assertion'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, nrwl-nx

We have a monorepo with a react project based on TypeScript and the [NX build framework](https://nx.dev/).

Unfortunately for our Jest tests we get this error message in the IDE (for every Jest property):

```
Property 'toMatchSnapshot' does not exist on type 'Assertion'. ts(2339)
```

We already tried some approaches (Github, Stackoverflow etc.) but unfortunately didn't get it to work.

Our current setup looks like this:

**apps/our-app-name/tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "files": [
    "../../node_modules/@nrwl/react/typings/cssmodule.d.ts",
    "../../node_modules/@nrwl/react/typings/image.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.tsx",
    "**/*.test.tsx",
    "**/*.spec.js",
    "**/*.test.js",
    "**/*.spec.jsx",
    "**/*.test.jsx"
  ]
}
```

**apps/our-app-name/tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
  },
  "files": [],
  "include": [],
  "exclude": ["cypress"],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

**apps/our-app-name/tsconfig.spec.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["jest", "node"],
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.test.tsx",
    "**/*.spec.tsx",
    "**/*.test.js",
    "**/*.spec.js",
    "**/*.test.jsx",
    "**/*.spec.jsx",
    "**/*.d.ts",
    "./jest.setup.ts"
  ],
  "files": [
    "../../node_modules/@nrwl/react/typings/cssmodule.d.ts",
    "../../node_modules/@nrwl/react/typings/image.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**apps/our-app-name/jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  displayName: 'our-app',
  preset: '../../jest.preset.js',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
    },
    crypto: require('crypto'),
  },
  transform: {
    '^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)': '@nrwl/react/plugins/jest',
    '^.+\\.[tj]sx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx'],
  coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/apps/pace-ingest',
};
```

**apps/our-app-name/jest.setup.ts**

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
```

**tsconfig.base.json (in the root)**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {},
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src", "public/static"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

What are we doing wrong or what is missing here?

Info: If we import `'@testing-library/jest-dom';` directly into the test files, it works. However, we don't want to add this import to every test file, we want to configure it globally.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if this will help but I was getting a similar error for matchers such as:

`Property 'toMatchObject' does not exist on type 'Assertion'`

I then spotted the following in the docs:

> The TypeScript examples from this page will only work as documented if you explicitly import Jest APIs

Essentially each test file needed something like this:

`import {expect, jest, test} from '@jest/globals';`

[This](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tomatchobjectobject) is worth a read.